# Google Keyword Planner CSV delimiter for PHP

Tags: php, html, csv, delimiter, separator

The Google Keyword tool was replaced with Google Keyword Planner and unfortunately, they changed the delimiter in the csv export.

Before this their csv export was comma delimited, now it's weird, it looks like this:

```
Campaign    Currency    Budget  Language    Networks    Ad group    Max      CPC    Keyword Avg. monthly searches   Competition Avg CPC Impr. share In account? In plan?    Headline    Description line 1  Description line 2  Display URL Destination URL
Ideas   USD     en  Google Search                                                       
Ideas   USD             Keywords like: Golf Equipment           505680  0.42    0.78                                
Ideas   USD             Keywords like: Golf Equipment       golf equipment  9900    1.00    0.59        N   Y                   
Ideas   USD             Keywords like: Golf Equipment       ford credit 110000  0.15    1.52        N   Y
```

I tried a lot of delimiters for php importing, but noting works...
My old code was:

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
```

Can you please tell me what delimiter is it? Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are downloading the excel version, i believe the delimiter is tab. Try this:

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, "\t")) !== FALSE)
```